# React native: debugging on device with local api server

Tags: reactjs, react-native

If i'm debugging with ios/android simulator i need to refer to the local server with `http://localhost:8080/api`. If i'm doing this on device, i should do `http://my_machinge_ip:8080/api`. Is there an elegant way to have the same DEV environment url all the time? I know, that there is way to determine if app is running on simulator or device, but this looks ugly :) Can i somehow use `my_machinge_ip` even if app is running on the same machine in simulator?

Comment: You should be definitely able to use host IP address even when running app on simulator. So I would use host IP in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your machine IP all to time, this will work when you are on a local machine and on a distant machine. This is the simplest way to have the same DEV environment URL all the time.